# How do I change a light's power with two bones using drivers?

Tags: rigging, bones, lighting, drivers, mathematics

I have a rig that has two bones named "cover" and "panel", to simplify lets say these two bones go from 0 to 150, I need it so that when cover is 150 and panel is 150, the light's wattage is 150, if cover gets turned to 0 but panel is 150, then the light's wattage is 0. Vice versa for when panel is 0 and cover is 150. What I have in my drivers is :

```
0 if (cover == 0) else panel*500 if (cover == 0.167 and panel < 0.3) else cover*898.201
```

> 0.167 being the maximum "cover" can go and 0.3 being the maximum "panel" can go.
>
> `panel*500` and `cover*898.201` just makes them both equal 150 when at max distance so ignore that.

What my problem is that operator "==" does not seem to work at all in blender for whatever reason.
It always will give me `cover*898.201` as the output even when the bone, "cover" equals 0.167, which should be giving me `panel*500` as the output.

Edit: To put this into context, the rig is for a device that has a flame on it, cover controls a cover that closes around the flame (aka, at 0 is closed and at 0.167 is open) and panel controls a sort of focus for the flame, where if the panel is open or “unfocused” (aka, at 0.3) then a point light (the light I want to control) is at 150 watts, and when panel closes or “focuses” (aka, at 0), the light is focused and the point light is off and then a spotlight is turned on. What I want is that so when cover is closed, the point light is 0w, when its open, the light is 150w. When the panel is focused, the light is 0w and when unfocused, its 150w.

Also I didn’t include in my original post that I need it so that when the cover is say, closed half way at 75w, and panel is then focused, then it would now go from 75w to 0w instead of 150w to 0w like if cover was fully open

Comment: Asking for `cover` to be **equal**  to `0.167` in floating-point world is a bit  much to expect. You would be better off asking for `cover` to be in a small range around `0.167`.  But that might make your expression rather long-winded. If you can explain what you expect the _functions_ of cover and panel to be.. their _behaviour_, we might be able to simplify it.

Comment: Added more context to the post to hopefully give you a better idea of what I am wanting to do.

Comment: Is [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2Mj8Zole/) something like where you want to go?

Comment: That is actually exactly what I am wanting to do. This works perfectly! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great  I'll make an answer of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the posted approach, your expression winds up a bit tangled. Although it might cost us a few more driver-connections, perhaps it can be simplified by breaking out the parts.

It seems we're looking for two controls, maybe named more suggestively: `Focus`, and `Dimmer`. They can be defined as 0-1 float Custom Properties on the Spot component of your light-combination.

- `Focus` will drive the intensity of the spot, as a multiplier of its maximum  strength.
- `1-Focus` will similarly drive the intensity of the point component. (So `Focus` becomes the 'Fac' in a linear mix between the point and spot)
- `Dimmer` multiplies the intensity of both components, (effectively, the intensity of the mix)
- For a more even transition between spot and point-lighting, `Focus` can also be used to control the 'Size' and 'Blend' of the spot.

[image]

[image]

If you're not happy with the strictly linear relationships, you can adjust the (Driver on X,Driven on Y) f-Curves associated with the driver expressions, in the Driver Editor.

[image]

(In this .blend, the Custom Properties are themselves driven by the location of the triangular slider-objects)